# layout manager cancelling set location of jlable

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, netbeans, layout-manager

i wrote my code like below and LABEL moved correctly:

```
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel label1=new JLabel("LABEL");
    JLabel label2=new JLabel("0");
    JButton btn1=new JButton("start");

    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
           Thread t=new Thread()
            {
              public void run()
              {
                  while(true)
                  {
                      try 
                      {
                          Thread.sleep(10);
                      } 
                      catch (Exception ex) 
                      {}
                      label2.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(label2.getText())+1));
                      label1.setLocation(label1.getX()+1, label1.getY());
                  }
               }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    });
```

but when i wrote in Netbeans Jframe it didn't move!
is it possible that problem is from JFrame layout manager??
How can i solve it?

At the same problem, when i comment line A of below code changing location of jLabel2 working correctly but when both line A and B aren't comment jLabel2 never move!!

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    Thread t=new Thread()
    { public void run()
      {    while(true)
          {   try 
              {  Thread.sleep(10);  } 
              catch (Exception ex) {}

              /* line A */
              jLabel1.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(jLabel1.getText())+1));

              /* line B */
              jLabel2.setLocation(jLabel2.getX()+1, jLabel2.getY());
          }
       }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Don't trying and update UI components outside the EDT. See [Concurrency with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: _"is it possible that problem is from JFrame layout manager??"_ - YES. Location is not applicable when using the layout managers. But you _should_ be using layout managers. See [Laying out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: You're trying to do some type of animation, and if so, then I suppose it's OK to use a null layout on the JPanel that holds the JLabel, but you will have to specifically set the JPanel with this layout. It won't come automatically. Also, yes, your Swing calls must be done on the Swing event thread. One easy way to do that is to use a Swing Timer instead of using a background thread directly.

Answer (score 1):

Again

- If you're animating a component, then the container that holds it needs to use a null layout. If you're not sure what layout it's using, ask it -- call `getLayout()` and print out the result.
- Use a Swing Timer not a background thread to drive your animation. This will ensure that you make Swing calls on the Swing event thread, something that your code is not doing.
- After moving your component, call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the *container* that holds it.

Comment: yes i want to animate label and increase value of another label together. jlabel2 return null layout. i also use timer for jlabel1 but not working and also call revalidate() and repaint() methods but not working again... :(

Comment: @Ahmad: if you need help for code that's not working, then you should post a [minimal runnable example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an edit to your question.